# True/false if/then/else shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/ShellShowsMenubar)

if $result == "false" 
then 
   xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/ShellShowsMenubar -n -t bool -s true
else
   xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/ShellShowsMenubar -n -t bool -s false
fi
```

It outputs no errors, but it also doesnt work.

Comment: Can you please try with
`if [ $result == false ]`

Please notice there are spaces between each characters and `false` is not inside double quotes

Comment: [Don't use $ on the left side of assignments](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC1066) and always copy paste your script to http://www.shellcheck.net/ to fix syntax violations

Comment: no output shown then?

Comment: Note that you probably don't need an `if` statement at all; `xfconf-query` has a `-T` option to toggle a boolean setting. I don't have it installed to test, so I am not sure 1) if you would still need `-t bool` if you used `-T`, or 2) how `-T` and `-n` interact.

Answer (score 4):

Your line:

```
if $result == "false"
```

tries to run a command named `true` or `false`, which both are valid keywords in bash, so you don't get an error. The extra arguments `==` and `false` don't do anything useful.

Running `true` returns a "success" exit code, so when `$result` is `true`, your code will follow the `if` branch and when it is `false`, it will follow the `else` branch.

To test the value of the string, use the standard syntax:

```
if [ "$result" = false ]
```

or the bash-specific:

```
if [[ $result = false ]]
```

`==` is supported in bash but you might as well use the standard operator `=` everywhere.

Answer (score -4):

```
xfconf-query -c xsettings -p /Gtk/ShellShowsMenubar -T
```

Comment: please add a brief explanation.

Comment: While this answer may indeed solve the issue it would be far more helpful if you explain why it solves the issue and why the original approach of OP did not work.